# Ruby way to do sum?

Tags: ruby

For me i could not think of better way but i believe there is one. Is there a ruby way (meaning: elegant way) to do the following method implementation?

```
def total(items)
  sum = 0
  items.each do |item|
    sum += item.value
  end
  sum
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to get the values, then [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) them using addition:

```
def total(items)
  items.map(&:value).reduce(:+)
end
```

Comment: Actually Rails implements a `sum` function on `Enumerable` which is implemented just like that: http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum reducing the needed code to just `items.sum(&:value)`

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke The OP did not state they are using Rails, so I won't assume they are.

Answer (score 3):

```
items.inject(0) { |memo,item| memo + item.value }
```

It may seem that no need to have 0 as initial value, but in case when array is empty it will return this initial value.

Second approach:

```
items.map(&:value).inject(0,:+)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, for example

```
items.reduce{|sum, el| sum + el.value}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def total(items)
  items.inject(0) do |total, item|
    total + item.value
  end
end
```